# How can I filter response in CoreWebView2

Tags: c#, .net, webview2

It doesn't appear that Webview2 handles svgz properly in some cases (especially tests loading from a file:// URI).  Since this is just a gzipped svg (svg WebView2 handles fine), I'd like to filter the response stream and check if it's svgz and decompress it on the fly.

Passing the stream through a gzip decompression shouldn't be a problem, however, I haven't found an event or way to check and filter the response stream with the Webview2/CoreWebView2 class.  The .WebResourceResponseReceived event is documented as being async to the navigation/loading of the response-content, but something like that sounds like it would work (if it were not async).

It may even be that I need to edit the response header to indicate content encoding is gzipped and Webview2 will auto decompress the stream, but again, I need to find the correct event where I have access to update the response headers or stream.

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/webresourcerequested?tabs=dotnet) appears to be a good place to start.

Comment: @SamAxe That's an excellent resource, but it appears that WebResourceRequested event-args contains a null Response for [at least] file:// resources. I believe this event is fired during request-time, and the implementer can choose to provide their own Response. I need an analogous event when the Response has been received, but Content has not yet Loaded/Navigated in the control.

Comment: The WebResourceResponseReceived is async as you say above. You cannot use it to find out about HTTP responses but not modify them. The only mechanism is what Sam says above. You'd need to fill in your own response during WebResourceRequest. Which would mean performing your own HTTP request via .NET APIs, getting the response, modifying it and then applying it to the WebResourceRequest response. Its not great because you won't have the same cookies and such performing the HTTP request on your own.